# How to Iteratively run Kmeans / Random Forest and compare accuracy

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means, random-forest

original data:

```
head(df.num_kmeans)
  datausage     mou   revenue calldrop handset2g handset3g smartphone
1  896804.7 2854801 40830.404    27515      7930     19040      20810
2  155932.1  419109  5512.498     5247      2325      2856       3257
3  674983.3 2021183 25252.265    21068      6497     13056      14273
4  522787.2 1303221 14547.380     8865      4693      9439      10746
5  523465.7 1714641 24177.095    25441      8668     12605      14766
6  527062.3 1651303 20153.482    18219      6822     11067      12994
  rechargecount rechargesum      arpu subscribers 
1          4461      235430 197704.10      105822             
2           843       39820  34799.21       18210             
3          2944      157099 133842.38       71351             
4          2278      121697 104681.58       44975              
5          2802      144262 133190.55       75860             
6          2875      143333 119389.91       63740
```

I have the following PCA data on which i am doing Kmeans clustering:

```
head(pcdffinal)
        PC1         PC2       PC3       PC4         PC5        PC6
 1 -9.204228 -2.73517110 2.7975063 0.6794614 -0.84627095  0.4455297
 2  2.927245  0.05666389 0.5085896 0.1472800  0.18193152  0.1041490
 3 -4.667932 -1.98176361 2.2751862 0.5347725 -0.43314927  0.3222719
 4 -1.366505 -0.40858595 0.5005192 0.4507366 -0.54996933  0.5533013
 5 -4.689454 -2.77185636 2.4323856 0.7387788  0.49237229 -0.4817083
 6 -3.477046 -1.84904214 1.5539558 0.5463861 -0.03231143  0.2814843

opt.cluster<-3
set.seed(115)
pccomp.km <- kmeans(pcdffinal,opt.cluster,nstart=25)

head(pccomp.km$cluster)
[1] 2 1 2 2 2 2
barplot(table(pccomp.km$cluster), col="steelblue")
```

[image]

```
pccomp.km$tot.withinss #For total within cluster sum of squares.
[1] 13172.59
```

We can also use a plot to illustrate the groups that the data have been arranged into.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
plot(pcdffinal[,1:2],col=(pccomp.km$cluster+1),main=paste('K-Means    Clustering result with k = ', opt.cluster,sep=" "),pch=20,cex=2)
points(pccomp.km$centers, pch=15,cex=2)#plotting the centres of the cluster as black squares
```

[image]

```
library("factoextra")
fviz_cluster(pccomp.km, data = pcdffinal, frame.type = "convex")+ theme_minimal()
```

[image]

```
df.num_kmeans<-df.num
df.num_kmeans$cluster.kmeans <- pccomp.km$cluster# is a vector of cluster assignment from kmeans() added as a column to the original dataset as
```

save this dataset & kmeans model for further use

```
saveRDS(pccomp.km, "kmeans_model.RDS")
write.csv(df.num_kmeans,"dfnum_kmeans.cluster.csv")

library(cluster)
clusplot(df.num_kmeans,pccomp.km$cluster,color = TRUE,shade=TRUE,labels = 2,lines = 0)
```

[image]

```
library(ggfortify)
autoplot(pccomp.km, data=pcdffinal, frame=TRUE,frame.type='norm')
```

[image]

Then i run random forest model and compute accuracy:

```
dfnum.kmeans <- read.csv("dfnum_kmeans.cluster.csv")
table(dfnum.kmeans$cluster.kmeans) # size of each cluster
```

convert cluster var into a factor

```
dfnum.kmeans$cluster.kmeans <- as.factor(dfnum.kmeans$cluster.kmeans)
is.factor(dfnum.kmeans$cluster.kmeans)
```

create training and test sets (75:25 split) using 'caret' package

```
set.seed(128) # for reproducibility
inTrain_kmeans <- caret::createDataPartition(y =   dfnum.kmeans$cluster.kmeans, p = 0.75, list = FALSE) 

training_kmeans <- dfnum.kmeans[inTrain_kmeans, ] 
testing_kmeans <- dfnum.kmeans[-inTrain_kmeans, ] 

set.seed(122)
control <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 10,allowParallel = TRUE)    
 modFit.rfcaret_kmeans <- caret::train(cluster.kmeans~ ., method = "rf",data =    training_kmeans, trControl = control, number = 25)   
 modFit.rfcaret_kmeans$finalModel
 pred.test_kmeans = predict(modFit.rfcaret_kmeans, testing_kmeans);    confusionMatrix(pred.test_kmeans, testing_kmeans$cluster.kmeans )
confusionMatrix(pred.test_kmeans, testing_kmeans$cluster.kmeans )$overall[1]
```

I would like to do Kmeans and random forest for a range of Ks say k=2:6 each time making plots for the respective k as well as saving the models as well as the data as a csv but each done separately for different k's.Then for random forest would like to import the above saved csv's, create train & test data,run random forest model,then predict for each test data and finally compute confusion matrix and accuracy ....thus iteratively get the solution

Need help to convert the above codes into an iterative with the counter i going from 2 till 6.

Comment: Based on your vidualization, I would assume that **k-means will not work on this data** no matter how much you play around. If you explore anything, then improve the **preprocessing**. Why do you try the random forests at all on bad clusters? By the Garbage-in-garbage-out principle, it won't be useful.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse  ...most of the times one does not have a choice regarding data...one has to go with whatever data is given....anyways here the intention to learn iterative procedures in R which i dont have a sound base....

Comment: Yes, but you have a choice of preprocessing and algorithms. Running already-bad k-means clusters additionally through a random forest clearly won't improve the already bad clusters...